# Difference between predcting multiple outputs and single output with random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict certain output features (6 in total) with random forest with the input features always being the same. I noticed that my random forest model always fits better when I am trying to predict each of these outputs with a separate model.

But when I try to predict all these outputs with just a single model the r2 score is worse than that of predicting these features with separate models.

I would interpret that my r2 score is getting averaged across all my output features. Is it right ?
And does it make any difference in predicting the outputs at once or with separate model even though the input features are the same for all the outputs that I am trying to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Predicting all together and separately are different because different outputs may require different splits. If you predict together, you constraint that they share the tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would a good way then to use separate model for each output ? Do I have to manually create model for each or is there a better way ?

Comment: It depends on the library if they allow creation of different models when there are more than one output variables. You need to look at library docs. O/w, it doesn't sound too hard to create a separate estimator object for each output variable.